# App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP Xcode7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, http, xcode7.1

guys. I set my info.plist as the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAhKJ.png)

however,there is still the problem there:" App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
" . I update my Xcode yestoday. the vision is 7.1 .  and simulator`s vision is 9.1
Is there similer question here?

Comment: There is a typo in your setting. You should use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`

Comment: Ahhhhh. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **Info.plist** and change that text with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and your issue will be resolved.

Or open **Info.plist** file in **Source Code** mode and replace the following lines:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```